# When can you omit using s after possessive nouns?

Tags: possessives, possessive-pronouns

It seems that in some cases `s` is not used after possessive nouns, for example, you would not say `Fuel's price went up` instead you would say `Fuel price went up`. However, the sentence `This car's price is too high` sounds okay with using the ending `s`.

Can someone please explain the examples I provided from a grammatical perspective, and when using `s` can be omitted with possessive nouns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

's or s' is never omitted with **possessive** (*genitive* case) nouns.

But some of your examples are not **possessive**, they are *attributive*.

Noun+noun compounds can work as attributive nouns where one noun modifies the other. See *noun adjunct*, *attributive noun*, or *qualifying noun*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct

A noun or noun phrase in English is only considered possessive when it is written with an actual apostrophe, as you would have with my child’s entertainer or a my children’s entertainer. Those are both possessives.

*Car prices went up.* - car modifies price (not all prices went up).
*Car colours have been changed to reflect fashion."

*This car's price went up.* - this particular car 'possesses' a particular price. 
*This car's colour has been changed."

Fowler's *Modern English Usage* states in the section "Possessive Puzzles":

> Five years' imprisonment, Three weeks' holiday, etc. Years and weeks
>   may be treated as possessives and given an apostrophe or as adjectival
>   nouns without one. The former is perhaps better, as to conform to what
>   is inevitable in the singular – a year's imprisonment, a fortnight's
>   holiday.